Can the mlmodern fonts be displayed in a dvi previewer?
I am trying to display the mlmodern fonts in a dvi previewer (yap, in my case).  Is this possible?  Or does the font not implement the bitmap glyphs?
UPDATE: YAP fails miserably to display mlmodern fonts.  Yet it is able to display (sometimes sub-optimally) other  fonts like crf-lm.  Anyone know why this is?

I don't know about yap, but generally DVI previewer are able to use Type1 fonts.

Yap has two different rendering methods: Pk and Dvips.  For some reason, the default rendering method is Pk (why might this be?).  In this rendering method the display of some fonts can be very sub-optimal.  In particular, mlmodern looks atrocious.  But if the rendering method is changed to Dvips (under the View menu), the font magically displays quite well --- as it should, anyways.
To change the default rendering method permanently, it must be changed to Dvips in the Options, under the View menu, in the Display tab.
Why would anyone ever need the Pk rendering method?  And why make it the default?
Thanks a lot to @keith77777 for his question and his own answer here: Is there an alternative to using yap.exe for rendering dvi files within MikTeX?.
